# Spark with latest Parquet version

Tags: apache-spark, dependencies, parquet

Using a spark2 application in a cluster, I suspect Parquet reader and/or writer of memory holes. I'd like to test with the last Parquet version.

As Spark2 dependencies are provided, how can I force spark to use the latest parquet version for

```
spark.read.parquet(sourcePath)
```

and

```
df.write
    .option("compression", "snappy")
    .option("parquet.block.size", PARQUET_BLOCK_SIZE.toString)
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .partitionBy("part")
    .parquet(targetDirectory)
```

? Thx